# Load Top Menu After page Load Magento 2

Tags: php, jquery, magento, magento2

I'm new to using Magento, I have a question for you.
How can I load the contents of the Magento Top menu into hover, only when you do the hover and not at the first landing?
Let me explain, I have a phtml file and I would like it to be loaded only when I'm hovering on the Top Menu

```
<?php
/**
 * @var $block Menu
 */

use MyStore\Widget\Block\Widget\Menu;

?>
<div class="header-widget-block">
    <?php if($block->getData('link')): ?>
        <a href="<?= $block->getData('link') ?>" class="header-widget-link">
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if($block->getData('image')): ?>
        <div class="header-widget-image d-lg-block">
            <img loading="lazy" src="<?= $block->getData('image') ?>" alt="<?= $block->getData('title') ? $block->getData('title')  : '' ?>">
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if($block->getData('title')): ?>
        <div class="header-widget-title">
            <?= $block->getData('title') ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if($block->getData('link')): ?>
        </a>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

This is my phtml file.
I would like if not possible for each hover as it is dynamic, that it is loaded at least after the complete loading of the page

Answer (score 0):

I would very much like to know this too. Our menu has around 1500 categories and this means at least twice that number in DOM elements, which is a performance killer, sometimes not necessary if the user does not initiate the menu at all.

Comment: This is not an answer and should be added as a comment to the question.